# Transition after rotate element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I made a simple rocket which moves between planets. I want the rocket to rotate to the planet is going and after that translate it / change its position to the planet clicked.

I managed to know which direction I want it to go but I can't figure out how to make the rotation first and after start the transition to move the rocket.

I apply the transorm from js once the user clicks one planet like this:

```
rocket.css({"top": POSITIONS[element].top, "left": POSITIONS[element].left});
setRocketOrientation(destination);
```

[*Codepen*](https://codepen.io/RominaMartin/pen/YEyaoY?editors=0010)

```js
const POSITIONS = {
  A: {top: "25%", left: "27%"},
  B: {top: "25%", left: "77%"},
  C: {top: "60%", left: "27%"},
  D: {top: "60%", left: "77%"}
}
var origin = "default";
var rocket = $("#rocket");

$(".planet").on("click", function(e) {
  let element =  $(this)[0].id;

  rocket.css({"top": POSITIONS[element].top, "left": POSITIONS[element].left});
  setRocketOrientation(element);
});

function setRocketOrientation (destination) {
  let orientation = null;
  switch(destination) {
    case "A":
      if(origin === "default" || origin === "D")
        orientation = "-45deg"
      else if(origin === "B")
        orientation = "-90deg"
      else if(origin === "C")
        orientation = "360deg"
      break;
    case "B":
      if(origin === "default" || origin === "C")
        orientation = "45deg"
      else if(origin === "A")
        orientation = "90deg"
      else if(origin === "D")
        orientation = "360deg"
      break;
    case "C":
      if(origin === "default" || origin === "B")
        orientation = "-120deg"
      else if(origin === "A")
        orientation = "-180deg"
      else if(origin === "D")
        orientation = "-90deg"
      break;
    case "D":
      if(origin === "default" || origin === "A")
        orientation = "120deg"
      else if(origin === "B")
        orientation = "180deg"
      else if(origin === "D")
        orientation = "90deg"
      break;
  }

  rocket.css({"transform": "rotate(" + orientation + ")"});
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #20202c 0%,#515175 100%);
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background:url(http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/stars.png) repeat center top;
}

.planet {
  height: 6em;
  position: absolute;
}

#A { top: 25%; left: 25%; }
#B { top: 25%; left: 75%; }
#C { top: 60%; left: 25%; }
#D { top: 60%; left: 75%; }

#rocket {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 35%;
  height: 5em;
  transition: all 2s ease-in;
/*   animation: shake 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s infinite alternate; */
}

@keyframes shake {
 from { transform: rotate(1deg); }
 to { transform-origin: center center; transform: rotate(-1deg); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <h1 class="title">Codevember <span class="number"> #1 </span></h1>
  <h2 class="type">Galaxy</h2>
  <div class="social"></div>
</div>

<img id="A" class="planet" src="https://i.imgsafe.org/a4/a4262a44b5.png">
<img id="B" class="planet" src="https://i.imgsafe.org/a4/a41a11c02c.png">
<img id="C" class="planet" src="https://i.imgsafe.org/a4/a41a18080a.png">
<img id="D" class="planet" src="https://i.imgsafe.org/a4/a4262a44d6.png">

<img id="rocket" src="https://i.imgsafe.org/a4/a404bdc703.png"></img>
```

Comment: I included the codepen contents as a snippet in the question, so that whatever might happen to codepen in the future, it will still be here. And also so that others can simply copy the snippet to their answers and experiment with it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep it in mind for next time I ask something!

Answer (score 6):

You can add just a [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function and set it's timer as the transition duration .

see beleow snippet :

```js
const POSITIONS = {
  A: {top: "25%", left: "27%"},
  B: {top: "25%", left: "77%"},
  C: {top: "60%", left: "27%"},
  D: {top: "60%", left: "77%"}
}
var origin = "default";
var rocket = $("#rocket");

$(".planet").on("click", function(e) {
  let element =  $(this)[0].id;
  let duration = $("#rocket").css("transitionDuration").replace("s","") * 1000;
  setRocketOrientation(element);
  
  setTimeout(function(){rocket.css({"top": POSITIONS[element].top, "left": POSITIONS[element].left});},duration)
  
});

function setRocketOrientation (destination) {
  let orientation = null;
  switch(destination) {
    case "A":
      if(origin === "default" || origin === "D")
        orientation = "-45deg"
      else if(origin === "B")
        orientation = "-90deg"
      else if(origin === "C")
        orientation = "360deg"
      break;
    case "B":
      if(origin === "default" || origin === "C")
        orientation = "45deg"
      else if(origin === "A")
        orientation = "90deg"
      else if(origin === "D")
        orientation = "360deg"
      break;
    case "C":
      if(origin === "default" || origin === "B")
        orientation = "-120deg"
      else if(origin === "A")
        orientation = "-180deg"
      else if(origin === "D")
        orientation = "-90deg"
      break;
    case "D":
      if(origin === "default" || origin === "A")
        orientation = "120deg"
      else if(origin === "B")
        orientation = "180deg"
      else if(origin === "D")
        orientation = "90deg"
      break;
  }

  rocket.css({"transform": "rotate(" + orientation + ")"});
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #20202c 0%,#515175 100%);
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background:url(http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/stars.png) repeat center top;
}

.planet {
  height: 6em;
  position: absolute;
}

#A { top: 25%; left: 25%; }
#B { top: 25%; left: 75%; }
#C { top: 60%; left: 25%; }
#D { top: 60%; left: 75%; }

#rocket {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 35%;
  height: 5em;
  transition: all 2s ease-in;
/*   animation: shake 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s infinite alternate; */
}

@keyframes shake {
 from { transform: rotate(1deg); }
 to { transform-origin: center center; transform: rotate(-1deg); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <h1 class="title">Codevember <span class="number"> #1 </span></h1>
  <h2 class="type">Galaxy</h2>
  <div class="social"></div>
</div>

<img id="A" class="planet" src="https://i.imgsafe.org/a4/a4262a44b5.png">
<img id="B" class="planet" src="https://i.imgsafe.org/a4/a41a11c02c.png">
<img id="C" class="planet" src="https://i.imgsafe.org/a4/a41a18080a.png">
<img id="D" class="planet" src="https://i.imgsafe.org/a4/a4262a44d6.png">

<img id="rocket" src="https://i.imgsafe.org/a4/a404bdc703.png"></img>
```

Comment: hope this help :)

Answer (score 4):

You can add a timeout to the alter step of the position.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    rocket.css({"top": POSITIONS[element].top, "left": POSITIONS[element].left});
}, 2000);
```

Then the position of the rocket is not changed until the rotate animation is finished.

Answer (score 4):

You can tap onto [transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) event on the rocket and after it's fired after rotating it you could unset it and trigger the proper `translate()` animation.

@EDIT: regarding the answers with `setTimeout` - setTimeout would work, but is not flawless. Timer is sometimes off and that's not really the best practice. Using `transitionend` is more efficient and more error-proof.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know about this event. Works like a charm!